# Tensorflow- How to share CNN's filter weights for different input channel?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

My 1-layer CNN neuron network's input data_set has 10 channels. If I set filter channel equal to 16, then there will be 10*16=160 filters.

I want to use same 16 filter channel's weights for each input channel. means only use 16 filters for my input data_set.  means the 10 input channels share same convolution filter weights.

Dose any one know how to do this in tensorflow? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the lower level `tf.nn.conv1d` with a `filters` arg constructed by tiling the same single-channel filters.

```
f0 = tf.get_variable('filters', shape=(kernel_width, 1, filters_out), initializer=...)
f_tiled = tf.tile(f0, (1, filters_in, 1))
output = tf.nn.conv1d(input, f_tiled, ...)
```

However, you would get the same effect (and it would be much more efficient and less error prone) to simply add all your input channels together to form a single-channel input then use the higher-level `layers` API.

```
conv_input = tf.reduce_sum(input, axis=-1, keepdis=True))
output = tf.layers.conv1d(conv_input, filters=...)
```

Note unless all your channels are almost equivalent, this is probably a bad idea. If you want to reduce the number of free parameters, consider multiple convolutions - a 1x1 to reduce the number of filters, other convolutions with wide kernels and non-linearities, then a 1x1 convolution to get back to a large number of filters. The `reduce_sum` in the above implementation is effectively a 1x1 convolution with fixed weights of `tf.ones`, and unless your dataset is tiny you'll almost certainly get a better result from learning the weights followed by some non-linearity.